# 32bit assembly - insertion sort doesn't work properly

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, insertion-sort

My task here is to add a code that sorts the array with insertion sort.
'printf' function prints a string
printArray prints the array

For some reason the array doesn't get sorted, and i cant find the reason why.
Help will be appreciated.

```
main:
        push MSG    ; print welcome message
        call printf
        add esp,4   ; clean the stack 

        call printArray ;print the unsorted array

        ;;;;;;;;;;add code here;;;;;;;;;;

        mov eax,1
loop1:
        mov ebx, array
        add ebx, eax

loop2:
        mov esi, ebx
        dec esi
        mov esi, [esi]      ;esi holds the value before what ebx points to
        cmp [ebx], esi
        ja endLoop2

        mov edx, esi
        mov esi, ebx
        dec esi
        mov ecx, [ebx]
        mov [esi], ecx
        mov [ebx], edx
        dec ebx
        cmp ebx, array
        ja loop2

endLoop2:
        inc eax
        cmp eax, 11
        jbe loop1

        ;;;;;;;end of your code;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

        call printArray

        mov eax, 1  ;exit system call
        int 0x80
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is full of 1 byte values, use `movb` instead of `mov` when loading and storing to memory.

Comment: Changed all incs and decs to add/sub 4, and now it seems to not print the array after the loops at all. Maybe it changed the address of the array(?!)
Doesn't make sense to me. Any other things you find wrong here?

Comment: I did that, and it messed the entire thing up.
Also your comment is wrong, since the array is of DB, and not ints.

Comment: Sorry I guess I misunderstood the problem.  I edited my answer given your new information.