# Insertion sort in assembler doesn't sort

Tags: sorting, assembly, insertion-sort

I'm trying to sort a array of numbers by Insertion sort but it not sort the numbers correctly. I've tried everything but it does not sort them As it should.
I would be happy if you could help me figure out where the problem and on how I can fix it thanks !!

```
section .rodata
MSG:    DB  "welcome to sortMe, please sort me",10,0
S1: DB  "%d",10,0 ; 10 = '\n' , 0 = '\0'

section .data

array   DB 5,1,7,3,4,9,12,8,10,2,6,11   ; unsorted array
len DB 12   

section .text
align 16
global main
extern printf

main:
push MSG    ; print welcome message
call printf
add esp,4   ; clean the stack 

call printArray ;print the unsorted array

    push ebp        ;save old frame pointer
    mov ebp,esp     ;create new frame on stack
    pusha
    mov esi,array
    mov ecx,8
 OuterLoop:
    mov ebx,ecx
    InnerLoop:
            add esi,ebx ;basically makes array[0] to array[ebx]
            mov eax,[esi] ;eax=array[ebx]
            sub esi,8
            mov edx,[esi] ; edx=array[ebx-1]
            add esi,8
            cmp eax,edx ; if(eax<edx)
            jle skip2 ; skip the loop
            ;else:
            mov [esi],edx ;array[ebx]=array[ebx-1]
            sub esi,8
            mov [esi],eax ; array[ebx-1]=array[ebx]
            add esi,8
            sub esi,ebx ; return the array to its original state (array[0])
            sub ebx,8
            cmp ebx,0
            jne InnerLoop
    skip1:
    add ecx,8
    cmp ecx,96
    jle OuterLoop

    popa            ;restore registers
    mov esp,ebp     ;clean the stack frame
    pop ebp
    push MSG        ; print welcome message (to divide between the unsorted and sorted)
    call printf
    add esp,4       ; clean the stack
    call printArray        

    mov eax, 1      ;exit system call
    int 0x80


printArray:
push ebp    ;save old frame pointer
mov ebp,esp ;create new frame on stack
pusha       ;save registers

mov eax,0
mov ebx,0
mov edi,0

mov esi,0   ;array index
mov bl,byte[len]
add edi,ebx ; edi = array size

print_loop:
cmp esi,edi
je print_end
mov al ,byte[array+esi] ;set num to print in eax
push eax
push S1
call printf
add esp,8   ;clean the stack
inc esi
jmp  print_loop
print_end:
popa        ;restore registers
mov esp,ebp ;clean the stack frame
pop ebp     ;return to old stack frame
ret

skip2:
sub esi,ebx ; return the array to the original state
jmp skip1
```

Comment: The first big problem I see is that you've defined an array of bytes, and are trying to sort them using 32-bit registers. This will pick up four bytes at once and try to sort them as a single big number. Either make your array `DD` or use 8-bit registers in your sort routine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334022/32bit-assembly-insertion-sort-doesnt-work-properly

Answer (score 0):

You're horribly mixing 3 sizes!
1. Array of bytes
2. Values of dwords
3. Steps of qwords

Once you've decided what size to use beware of this code. In its current qword form it does an extra iteration!  (use `jl OuterLoop`)

```
cmp ecx,96
jle OuterLoop
```

Why don't you use MOVZX to EAX in this line? It's much cleaner.

```
mov al ,byte[array+esi] ;set num to print in eax
```

The same applies to

```
mov bl,byte[len]
```

By putting `mov esi,array` right after `OuterLoop:` you can avoid that ugly detour via SKIP2.

Comment: Yes you are right I have to use dword but I did not understand what you mean when you say to me "use jl OuterLoop" 
Because this line it not sort properly ??

Comment: Once you've changed the number 96 into 48 to accomodate dwords there will still be an extra iteration because with **jle** ECX will take on these values : 4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48. That is 12 iterations (the last one compares the twelfth element with an non-existing thirteenth element). An array with 12 elements only needs 11 comparisons!

Comment: Sorry but I changed everything you said but it still does not work you have another idea why this is sort wrong?

Comment: Please add your reworked program as an EDIT to the original question.